# How to use Makefile implicit rule to build a file that doesn't exist in the same directory of the Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following folder structure:

```
src
 file1.c
 file2.c
 Makefile
 - config
     file3.c
```

In the makefile, I use the implicit rule to build all source files:

```
%.o:%.c
  $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

I want to build file3.c as well, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: I think you are misquoting the implicit rule. The actual rule uses the source (`file1.c`) to build the object (`file1.o`). The rule you posted appears to do the opposite. I will assume that you intend the usual `file1.c -> file1.o`.

Comment: Yes exactly. It is a typo and fixed. Thanks for your note

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to write an explicit rule for `file3.o`:

```
file3.o: config/file3.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

The elegant way is to use the [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) directive, to tell Make where to search for source files:

```
vpath %.c config
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The `vpath` solution doesn't work (file3.c is ignored). I receive this message: `make: *** No rule to make target 'file3.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`  The explicit rule works, but I don't think it is the best approach, as I have the same recipe written twice (the same compilation command)

Comment: @AhmedAdel: Wait... *"written twice"?* You don't have to write the implicit rule, it's implicit. And I've tested the `vpath` solution... Which version of Make are you using (You can find out with `make -v`.)

Comment: I mean I have to write `$(CC) -c -o @< @$` twice. make -v gives GNU Make 3.82.90

Comment: I don't know why the `vpath` approach is giving you that error.

Comment: Most likely it's because they didn't add the vpath correctly / in the wrong place.  However, the version of GNU make being used is VERY odd.  `3.82.90` was the first release candidate for GNU make 4.0.  It's known to have a number of problems (that's why it's a release candidate).  Wherever you got that version of make, you should delete it and find somewhere to get a real, released version of GNU make.  I can't say whether this is the problem or not, without seeing the actual makefile you used.